# Check if two elements exist in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to know how i can determine if two elements in a list exist. For example the setup would look like this:

```
liste = {"b", "d1", "a","z"}
MemberQ[{{"b", "a"}}, liste]
```

One problem i have is that it should not depend on the order of the two element, i.e. {"b", "a"} == {"a", "b"} that i want to check. I just want to know if these exist in a given list.

Comment: Hello, have a look at the documentation for `ContainsAll` , cheers!

Comment: Intersection can do this: `Intersection[liste, {"b", "a"}] != {}`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"b", "d1", "a", "z"};

ab = {"a", "b"};

ContainsAll[list, ab]
```

True

```
SubsetQ[list, ab]
```

True

```
Last @ UniqueElements[{list, ab}] == {}
```

True

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"b", "d1", "a", "z"};

ab = {"a", "e"};
```

An alternative is the following:

```
Thread[# -> Thread[Lookup[Counts[Catenate[{list, #}]], #] &@# > 1]] &@ab

(*{"a" -> True, "e" -> False}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `OrderlessPatternSequence`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f[k_List, elems_List] := 
  If[Cases[k, {OrderlessPatternSequence[Sequence @@ elems, ___]}, 
     All] == {}, False, True];

test = {{"b", "c", "a", "e", "c"}, {"a", "e", "c", "d", "a"}, {"d", 
    "d", "e", "c", "d"}, {"a", "e", "d", "d", "d"}, {"e", "b", "d", 
    "d", "a"}};
```

---

*Usage:*

```
f[#, {"a", "b"}] & /@ test
```

> {True, False, False, False, True}

```
f[#, {"b", "c", "e"}] & /@ test
```

> {True, False, False, False, False}